# How to type in both English and an RTL language in LyX

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I wish to write a (math) document in Hebrew, but that will contain some English (and math),
currently the LyX starts a new document in LTR and I do not know how to change the language to Hebrew (I was told that F11 or F12 might work, but they didn't).

My question is: how can I make a keybord shortcut to change the language to Hebrew, and how can I define a new document to be RTL ?

Help is very much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define Lyx to work in Hebrew, use this guide:
[Hebrew for Lyx setup](http://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew)

Good luck!

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.